# External versioning (external or external_gte)

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently working on a project which has a "projection" storage implemented using Elasticsearch. I have a few questions about external versioning.

First of all in general, in documentation it is said

> external_gte version type is meant for special use cases and should be used with care. If used incorrectly, it can result in loss of data
>   Blockquote
>   Why exactly it is so? Can you provide more details?

In my case in primary storage let's say I keep a set of entities and every single of them has a version number. And now it is possible to perform two kind of operations:

User make changes to a single entity which will internally cause version of entity be incremented. Then system schedules an operation which will create a document based on entity data and then index in Elasticsearch.

Someone from support team would like to recreate/refresh projection storage based on data kept in primary storage using bulk request. In this case version of entity might not change.

So, I thought of using external/external_gt for a first case and external_gte for second scenario. Another option is to use external_gte version type for both scenarios but I'm wondering what is a reason not to use it?

Comment: One question would be why does the support team need to reindex data if it hasn't changed in the primary storage? i.e. sending a document with the same version number as currently in ES would not need to trigger an index operation anyway.

Comment: There are 2 cases: 1) Exceptional situation, when we have a bug in the code and we don't want to change a version of this entity. 2) The same message can be consumed multiple times. To avoid Version conflict exception we'd like to consume all the messages.

Comment: Is it possible that more than one users would change the same entity at the same moment? Also what should happen if a user changes an entity while the support tries to reindex it at the same moment?

Comment: 1) It's not possible, primary storage guarantees optimistic concurrency. 2) Nothing bad, in this case we schedule reindex only for this one entity.

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation author meant that if versioning is not coordinated well in external systems , it will result in data loss. i.e , indexing with a higher version accidently after initial data load . As long as you have all systems which does indexing in control - i dont see any issues,